# quickly replace content between quote, bracket ？

Tags: cut-copy-paste

“hello world”
“need be replaced by hello world”

What I do is put cursor in first line, issue command `yi"`
and then move cursor to second line, issue `vi"p`

I want to know is there any more convenient way to do this task

Comment: Sure: `Ypjdd` ;) But seriously, not really. At least not if you and I have the same definition of convenient. (Are you just referring to number of keystrokes?) That's a pretty short pair of commands, if you ask me. You're leveraging the power of Vim well.

Answer (score 1):

Try defining some normal mode mappings in your ~/.vimrc.   For this example, let's sacrifice the builtin `gq` and `gQ` functionality.

```
" Yank the text inside quotes to the 'a' register
nnoremap gq "ayi"
" Replace the text inside quote from the contents of the 'a' register
nnoremap gQ vi""ap
```

Now you can use `gq` to yank the text inside quotes and `gQ` to replace the text inside quotes.